# How to alter table

Tags: foreign-key-relationship

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[INVS_ITEM_LOCATIONS](
    [DEPARTMENT_CODE] [varchar](3) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [IM_INV_NO] [numeric](10, 0) NOT NULL,
    [LOCATION_CODE] [varchar](2) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [CURR_QTY] [numeric](10, 0) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__INVS_ITEM__CURR___1352D76D]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [DO_QTY] [numeric](10, 0) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__INVS_ITEM__DO_QT__1446FBA6]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [ALLOC_QTY] [numeric](10, 0) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__INVS_ITEM__ALLOC__153B1FDF]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [YOB_QTY] [numeric](10, 0) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__INVS_ITEM__YOB_Q__162F4418]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [FOC_QTY] [numeric](10, 0) NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__INVS_ITEM__FOC_Q__17236851]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [USER_CREATED] [varchar](25) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [DATE_CREATED] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [USER_MODIFIED] [varchar](25) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [DATE_MODIFIED] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [INVS_ITEM_LOCATIONS_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DEPARTMENT_CODE] ASC,
    [IM_INV_NO] ASC,
    [LOCATION_CODE] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

this is my table name how can i delete primary key in im_inv_ni and location_ code

and also i should add foriegn key to im_inv_no....pls help

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ALTER TABLE -statements. More information can be found here http://ss64.com/ora/table_a_cons.html.

The needed statements are

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].INVS_ITEM_LOCATIONS DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE [dbo].INVS_ITEM_LOCATIONS ADD CONSTRAINT <name of fk> FOREIGN KEY (<columns>) REFERENCES <table>(<columns>);
```